# Ecto models changeset errors

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a model with a string field, that must be at least two characters long :

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> validate_length(:name, min: 2)
end
```

The problem is that changeset.errors, when rightfully filled, returns :

```
[name: {"should be at least %{count} characters", 2}]
```

Is it a bug, if not how can I interpolate this tuple ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using it with Phoenix, it will be automatically taken care for you in `form_for/4` or when generating a JSON structure. Otherwise, you need to traverse it yourself and call `String.replace(string, "%{count}", Integer.to_string(count))`.

Comment: I use Phoenix indeed with form_for but this one is passed to put_flash to display the error on #create.